# How to disable Angularjs completely after the page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to disable all the functionalities provided by Angularjs, but only after the pages and all components have been loaded fully.For example "ng-click" should not work any more.

I tried to set the "ng-click" attr to null but, it still works when clicked.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean...page is rendered with the help of angularjs, once page loaded nothing will work?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you really want to do that, you need to rethink why you are using angular in the first place.

Comment: @Asik: Exactly, I don't want the page to be functional anymore. Its just I will be playing around with my code.

Comment: there won't be much fun left without angular :(

Comment: This makes no sense. Deeper answer is that you really cannot. Once you've marked it as an angular application, angular internally attaches to various events and registers javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy angular app `$scope` that means it will disable only two way binding of scope variables using `$scope.$destroy()` method nothing more than that(If you want to disable two way binding on start up load then you need call `$destroy()` in `$timeout`).

But the event listener won't get disabled from angular app which are register while angular app is initialized on page. You can only achieve this by maintaining any flag (this is hacky way).

[**Here is Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13398/) which demonstrate what i want to say.

Thanks.

Comment: @me_digvijay did you get a chance to look at my answer. does it helpful to you?